# Migration Process In API Connect v5 to v10

Tags: migration, apic

We had CP4I Platform & We want to migrate v5 to v10 in cp4i. So anyone can help or share link how we can implement migration process in cp4i.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.